# How to make my Material UI Modal responsive?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, responsive

I created a Modal with a Carousel inside of it and I want it to be responsive.
I tried out several CSS settings that I found here on StackOverflow, but none of them worked for me. How can I fix it?

**CSS:**

```
media: {
    width: "auto",
    paddingTop: "56.25%" // 16:9
  },
modalCard: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    width: "50%",
    aspectRatio: "16 / 9",
    margin: "0 auto"
  }
```

**Rnd.jsx:**

```
<Card className={classes.modalCard}>
    <Carousel autoPlay={false} indicators={false} animation="slide">
        {images.map((img, index) => {
            return (<CardMedia className={classes.media} image={img.imgPath} />
        );
      })}
    </Carousel>
</Card>
```

**The project:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-3uggr5?file=/Rnd.jsx:131-139

[image]

(Off question: Why do I get that warning?)

Comment: I checked your codes and there is no problem. it works. Do you still need help

Comment: It is not working, you can see on the picture. Open the modal, then increase your window size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel`.

I created sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-chhzov?file=/Rnd.jsx:124-262) so you can check it.